# Proper syntax for "if" statement in J/Link

Tags: java, if-statement, wolfram-mathematica, jlink

When writing in Java within Mathematica (using J/Link), do I use Java or Mathematica syntax  for an If-Then statement?

This question is not about any particular code. The answer should be the same, regardless of the code being used. I know how to write using either syntax, I just don't know which one to use.

Comment: providing the code giving you issues might help.

Comment: Post the code so we can all see.  My guess is that it's not working because of some other mistake that you're making (e.g. using == to compare Strings instead of equals).

Comment: I don't think code helps here; should JLink utilize Mathematica or Java syntax? I suppose examples of the two could be given, but they would be no more elucidating. The correct comment is, "Well, have you tried obvious statements in each syntax to see which works?"

Comment: @NathanielFord: Let's say the OP responds, "Yes I have." What's the next question we'd ask? "Well, what was that obvious code?"

Comment: @DavidRobinson To be honest, I hadn't tried both syntaxes yet. However, that's because when the first syntax (Mathematica syntax) didn't work, I had to put the code away to go and eat dinner. I figured I'd throw the question up here so that when I came back I'd know if my instinct was right and that the syntax was wrong, or if it was something else.

I also thought it would be worthwhile to have the question and answer up here on SO because I was unable to find an answer in any of the documentation I was reading, and I thought someone else in the future might have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really write java inside Mathematica. J/Link simply allows you to call Java functions via Mathematica and manipulate Mathematica objects-created based on Java objects. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html#15615)

Hence you'll be writing if statements in Mathematica syntax. `If[condition, t, f]`

On a side note, the other side of J/Link allows you to use Mathematica from Java. Likewise you'll be writing java there in the majority of your code and calling something along the lines of `ml.Evaluate("If[condition, t, f]")` if you need to compute using Mathematica.
For anyone interested, .NET/Link works the same.

Comment: Actually, you can write your own Java classes inside of Mathematica. I'm mostly using this page as a guide: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i1/contents/UI_With_JLink/UI_With_JLink_3.html
However, they never cover If-Then statements.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, what I'm getting at is this line from your article: "we are writing the same sort of code that we would write in Java, except using Mathematica syntax." Notice how everything is still really Mathematica syntax - so instead of `button.SetSize(100, 30)`, you're using button@SetSize[100, 30].